# Need help with simplex noise skew transformation

Tags: algorithms, transformation, simplex, noise

I am reading a paper about simplex noise.
http://knielsen-hq.org/simplex_noise_skew_factor.pdf

For whatever reason I can't figure out the result they got here. My brain is just goin kapoot.

> To understand this, let us first consider the general form of the
> transformation from simplexcoordinates (,) in the grid spanned by
> → and → to the rectangular coordinates (,). It
> is
>
> =+
>
> =+
>
> where →= (,) and →= (,). So this
> requires 4 multiplications in the general case. However, we can freely
> choose which simplex grid to use! So we can try to choose one
> thatreduces the computational work needed.First, we can choose the
> orientation of the grid so that → and → are symmetric around
> thediagonal =. Then = and =, so we can write the
> transformation as
>
> =(−)+(+)
>
> =(−)+(+)

I've tried a few things by rewriting the eqautions as follows

0 = au + bv - x

0 = bu + av     - y

0 =           x - y

but I need a little guidance. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Which part of the fairly long conclusion is the result you are not figuring out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $x = au + bv$, insert the "fancy version of zero", $-bu+bu$ then regroup.  \begin{align*}
x &= au +(-bu+bu) + bv  \\
  &= au - bu + bu + bv  \\
  &= (a - b)u + b(u + v)  \\
\end{align*}
Similarly, make the indicated substititions, commute the addition, then insert "$-bv+bv$".  \begin{align*}
y &= cu+dv  \\
  &= bu+av  \\
  &= av + (-bv+bv) + bu  \\
  &= av -bv + bv + bu  \\
  &= (a-b)v + b(u+v)
\end{align*}